# How to know when are menu items in activity created?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-toolbar, menuitem

I have an activity with a Toolbar showing an settings menu.

When I access the menu items via

```
            val icon0 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, id0, null)
            (findViewById<View>(R.id.zone0) as? ItemView)?.setIcon(icon0)
```

in onCreate(...) of my activity the app crashes because findViewById returns null.

A few seconds after start, however I get a nun-null result from findViewById. 'zone0' is an ImageView located in the ToolBar.

Please note that I am NOT using fragments. I want to know - within the scope of my activity - WHEN my menu item view 'zone0' is accessible. From the docs I didn't see any callbacks indicating this.

From docs I read about menus:

> Changing menu items at runtime
>
> After the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), it retains an instance
> of the Menu you populate and will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() again
> unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should
> use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and
> not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.
>
> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur
> during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the
> onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object
> as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or
> disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu()
> callback.)
>
> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
> each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
> open when menu items are presented in the app bar. When an event
> occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
> invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call
> onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Is there a solution to get notified when the menu items are available ?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: No, even in onCreateOptionsMenu() where I inflate the menu from XML the menu item views are still null. I have tested it.